# Difference between function trunc() Vs AND in datetime column

Tags: sql, oracle

Is this query

```
select 1 from tab1 where
TRUNC(tab1.T_DATE) = TRUNC(to_date('2018-08-31','yyyy-mm-dd'))
```

Similar to this ?

```
select 1 from tab1 where    
        tab1.T_DATE >= to_date('2018-08-31','yyyy-mm-dd')
        And tab1.T_DATE < to_date('2018-09-01','yyyy-mm-dd')
```

Then when I need to use function Trunc() ? I am asking the difference because I have a query using Trunc() and the query needs index(sure I don't want to use FBI), so I am replacing the function with `AND`. However I am worried that there might be some difference.

Data Example:

```
31/08/2018
31/08/2018
31/08/2018
31/08/2018
31/08/2018
31/08/2018
31/08/2018
31/08/2018
31/08/2018
31/08/2018
31/08/2018
31/08/2018 10:19:02 PM
31/08/2018 07:55:01 PM
31/08/2018 1:08:54 PM
31/08/2018 1:18:44 PM
31/08/2018 1:45:34 PM
31/08/2018 1:53:57 PM
31/08/2018 1:59:01 PM
31/08/2018 2:04:19 PM
31/08/2018 4:06:56 PM
```

Comment: Yes, it's equivalent. And TRUNC will not use an index :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are asking if these are equivalent:

```
where TRUNC(tab1.T_DATE) = TRUNC(to_date('2018-08-31','yyyy-mm-dd'))

where tab1.T_DATE >= to_date('2018-08-31','yyyy-mm-dd') and
      tab1.T_DATE < to_date('2018-09-01','yyyy-mm-dd')
```

Yes.  They both bring back all values of `T_DATE` on 2018-08-31, regardless of the date.  `TRUNC()` when applied to a date removes the time component.  Hence, it is not needed on the right side of the first expression.

I would write this as:

```
where tab1.T_DATE >= date '2018-08-31' and
      tab1.T_DATE < date '2018-09-01'
```

because this can use an index on `tab1(T_DATE)`.

Comment: what is the difference between `TO_DATE` and `DATE` ? and using `to_date` will stop the index from reading the column ?

Comment: @Baalback if you use within the literal like `to_date('2018-08-31','yyyy-mm-dd')`, not problem. While using as `to_date(tab1.T_DATE,'....')=....` yields problem from the performance point of view.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan Then for good practice I can add `date '2018-08-31'` right

Comment: @Baalback: `TO_DATE` is proprietary syntax while `DATE 'yyyy-mm-dd'` is Standard SQL (cleaner, shorter and supported by Oracle since 15+(?) years)

Comment: @Baalback: `date '2018-08-31'` is a date literal, just as `'ABC'` is a string literal and 123 is a number literal. `to_date('2018-08-31', 'yyyy-mm-dd')` on the other hand is a function call on a string that returns a date. So why would you give the DBMS a string and then let it apply a function on it to return the date, when you can give it the date right away?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner sure its better you give date right away however if i am running this select on several databases , ill have a concern that those database doesn't have the same date format right ? I mean if a database have default format lets say 'mm/dd/yyyy' and other dd/mm/yyyy then the query will throw error in format is wrong am I right ?

Comment: @Baalback . . . The `DATE` keywords always accepts the ISO standard format YYYY-MM-DD.

Comment: @Baalback Actually the `DATE` keywords **only** accepts the ISO standard format `YYYY-MM-DD`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the two queries do exactly the same thing.

Oracle lacks a real `DATE` datatype. Its `DATE` is actually a `DATETIME`, which has confused people again and again :-) You can get to a real data column by using a check constraint that rejects dates with a time part or with a trigger that removes that part.

As to your table that really does have datetimes and the two queries selecting a day's rows:

The first query is more readable. People often hold against that, that the second query can benefit from indexes on the `T_DATE` column. However, as Oracle features function indexes, you would then use an index on `TRUNC(t_date)` and the argument is void.

Comment: I would consider creating an unneeded index void :-) What if you need to cover more than one day?

Comment: @dnoeth: Why do you consider an index on `TRUNC(t_date)` unnecessary, but an index on `t_date` necessary? Quite often only date ranges are requested (and not time ranges) and all queries look like the ones posted. So why create an index on `t_date` then, when we actually want the days? And as to the queries: One doesn't benefit from any of our `t_date` indexes and the other doesn't benefit from any of our `trunc(t_date)` indexes. Same argument for both queries, I'd say.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner As I noted I don't want to use FBI, because the application is old and there some old query using `T_DATE` without `trunc()`  so I prefer to create index without FBI so the old query get benefit from it, beside for some other queries( I don't why) they need to use t_date without trunc()

Comment: Is Oracle actually to stupid to recognize that `to_date('2018-08-31','yyyy-mm-dd')` or `date '2018-08-31'` is a constant?

Comment: Definitively **wrong advice** for tables range partitioned on the date column. The `TRUNC(t_date)` disables partition pruning.